# Long Access token in FB

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a social FB login in my Android App. I ask the user for permissions, and after they permit the App, it provides me with a Long Access token, which has an expiry for 60 days. Now, I send this data(social_id and auth_token) to my server where I read all the details of the user.

My question is that can I have the control of user's account once I've the user's long access token?? Because now I've its long access token, which I can refresh on a daily basis from my server, hence extending its lifetime every now and then. Is this how it works? If it works like this, then what's the use of providing an expiry time for the token?

Even if he logs out of the app, I can still refresh its token without letting the user know. In short, I can have a full control of his/her account. Am I correct? Correct me please if I'm wrong!!!

Comment: _“Even if he logs out of the app, I can still refresh its token without letting the user know”_ – no, you can not. Only short-lived tokens can be exchanged for long-lived/extended ones – and for you to get a fresh short-lived token, the user has to interact with your app.

Comment: So, you mean to say whenever I refresh long-auth token, I need the short lived token for which user needs to re-login after 60 days?

Comment: You can not “refresh” a long-lived token at all. The only thing you can do, is get a long-lived token from a short-lived one – and that long-lived one will be valid for up to 60 days from that point on. So if your long-lived token has expired, you need to get a _new_ one – and that means you need a current short-lived token first, because only those can be exchanged for a long-lived one.